# Yocto Eclipse ADT plugin fails during configure

Tags: linux, eclipse, configure, yocto, bitbake

I'm trying to use the Yocto Project Eclipse ADT plugin using the manual as a reference with a standalone pre-built toolchain created by running `bitbake <recipename> -c populate_sdk`, then running `poky-glibc-x86_64-<recipename>-x86-toolchain-2.0.sh`, specifying default locations. I've sourced the environment-setup in `opt/poky/2.0`. My Toolchain Root Location is pointing to `/opt/poky/2.0` and my sysroot is pointing at `/opt/poky/2.0/sysroots/x86-poky-linux`.

I was able to compile a "Hello, world" program using this enviromnent, but with a larger project I hit errors during the Build Project step.

Here's the relevant part of my config.log:

```
Configured with: /home/presslertj/poky/build/tmp/work-shared/gcc-5.2.0-r0/gcc-5.2.0/configure --build=x86_64-linux --host=x86_64-pokysdk-linux --target=i586-poky-linux --prefix=/opt/poky/2.0/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr --exec_prefix=/opt/poky/2.0/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr --bindir=/opt/poky/2.0/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/i586-poky-linux --sbindir=/opt/poky/2.0/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/i586-poky-linux --libexecdir=/opt/poky/2.0/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/i586-poky-linux --datadir=/opt/poky/2.0/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/share --sysconfdir=/opt/poky/2.0/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/etc --sharedstatedir=/opt/poky/2.0/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/com --localstatedir=/opt/poky/2.0/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/var --libdir=/opt/poky/2.0/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/lib/i586-poky-linux --includedir=/opt/poky/2.0/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/include --oldincludedir=/opt/poky/2.0/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/include --infodir=/opt/poky/2.0/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/share/info --mandir=/opt/poky/2.0/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/share/man --disable-silent-rules --disable-dependency-tracking --with-libtool-sysroot=/home/presslertj/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-nativesdk-pokysdk-linux --with-gnu-ld --enable-shared --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-threads=posix --enable-multilib --enable-c99 --enable-long-long --enable-symvers=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-pch --program-prefix=i586-poky-linux- --without-local-prefix --enable-target-optspace --enable-lto --enable-libssp --disable-bootstrap --disable-libmudflap --with-system-zlib --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-linker-build-id --with-ppl=no --with-cloog=no --enable-checking=release --enable-cheaders=c_global --without-isl --with-gxx-include-dir=/not/exist/usr/include/c++/5.2.0 --with-build-time-tools=/home/presslertj/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/i586-poky-linux/bin --with-sysroot=/not/exist --with-build-sysroot=/home/presslertj/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/piu --enable-targets=all --enable-poison-system-directories --with-mpfr=/home/presslertj/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-nativesdk-pokysdk-linux --with-mpc=/home/presslertj/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-nativesdk-pokysdk-linux --enable-nls --enable-__cxa_atexit
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.2.0 (GCC) 
configure:2971: $? = 0
configure:2960: i586-poky-linux-gcc -m32 -march=pentium-m --sysroot=/opt/poky/2.0/sysroots/x86-poky-linux -V >&5
i586-poky-linux-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
i586-poky-linux-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:2971: $? = 1
configure:2960: i586-poky-linux-gcc -m32 -march=pentium-m --sysroot=/opt/poky/2.0/sysroots/x86-poky-linux -qversion >&5
i586-poky-linux-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
i586-poky-linux-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:2971: $? = 1
configure:2991: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3013: i586-poky-linux-gcc -m32 -march=pentium-m --sysroot=/opt/poky/2.0/sysroots/x86-poky-linux  -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types  -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed conftest.c  >&5
configure:3017: $? = 0
configure:3065: result: yes
configure:3068: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:3070: result: a.out
configure:3076: checking for suffix of executables
configure:3083: i586-poky-linux-gcc -m32 -march=pentium-m --sysroot=/opt/poky/2.0/sysroots/x86-poky-linux -o conftest  -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types  -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed conftest.c  >&5
configure:3087: $? = 0
configure:3109: result: 
configure:3131: checking whether we are cross compiling
configure:3139: i586-poky-linux-gcc -m32 -march=pentium-m --sysroot=/opt/poky/2.0/sysroots/x86-poky-linux -o conftest  -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types  -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed conftest.c  >&5
configure:3143: $? = 0
configure:3150: ./conftest
/home/presslertj/workspace/HMM/configure: ./conftest: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
configure:3154: $? = 126
configure:3161: error: in `/home/presslertj/workspace/HMM':
configure:3163: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
```

I think the most important line of this might be:

```
/home/presslertj/workspace/HMM/configure: ./conftest: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Which looks to me like it's looking in the wrong place for ld-linux.so.2.
Also, when running build, Eclipse's terminal spits out the following lines:

```
ENV key HOST_CC_ARCH is NULL
ENV key TOOLCHAIN_OPTIONS is NULL
ENV key SELECTED_OPTIMIZATION is NULL
ENV key TARGET_ARCH is NULL
ENV key OECMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS is NULL
ENV key OECMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS is NULL
ENV key STAGING_DIR_HOST is NULL
ENV key STAGING_DIR_NATIVE is NULL
ENV key CROSS_DIR is NULL
ENV key OECMAKE_EXTRA_ROOT_PATH is NULL
ENV key EXTERNAL_TOOLCHAIN is NULL
ENV key STAGING_DATADIR is NULL
```

I'm guessing that one of these variables needs to be specified so that ld-linux.so.2 is found but I don't know which, and I feel like I might've missed some critical step. What is causing this error? Have I misconfigured my environment?

Comment: What if you `apt-get install ia32-libs`? Seen in http://www.howtodoityourself.org/how-to-fix-libld-linux-so-2-bad-elf-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory.html

Comment: I tried that and resolved this error. I had assumed that I should use the linker/loader of the pre-built toolchain, but I guess I was over-thinking. If you  make this an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As read in [How to fix /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory](http://www.howtodoityourself.org/how-to-fix-libld-linux-so-2-bad-elf-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory.html):

> This will happen only on 64 bit systems, the cause is the fact that 32
>   bit libraries are missing from the system, so you can easily fix this
>   issue by installing the 32 bit libraries on your system.
>
> So if you encounter this error /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF
>   interpreter: No such file or directory this is how you can fix it:

To fix it:

> On any RPM based distribution (CentOS/RedHat/Fedora/Suse/Mandriva):
>
> ```
> yum -y install glibc.i686
> ```
>
> On any DEB based distribution (Debian/Ubuntu/Mint/Crunchbang):
>
> ```
> apt-get update
> apt-get install ia32-libs
> ```